# How to find where an unauthenticated user connects from

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

We are seeing some "*unauthenticated users*" when I run the command `show full processlist` in mysql (v5.6).

```
| Id       | User                 | Host                  | db           | Command     | Time     | State                | Info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | Rows_sent| Rows_examined |
| 29285830 | unauthenticated user | connecting host       | NULL         | Connect     |    NULL  | login                | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |        0 |             0 |
```

**`--skip-name-resolve` is ON.**

We have a monitoring agent, and a bunch of webservers and backend machines querying the database.

I am trying to write a python script which does `ssh` to the remote database, runs `netstat` and then runs `show full processlist` in MySQL and compares the connected IP addresses. However, the unauthenticated user's connection is very shortlived (less than a couple of seconds) and I don't get the IP address correctly. Is this the right approach or is there a better way to find the IP address of the unauthenticated user? There are about 1000+ connections.

Comment: You might want to read --》 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983400/what-does-unauthenticated-user-mean-in-mysql

Comment: So just to putting in simple words - you cannot from mysql. The user is still unauthenticated. You might want to try with system commands: lsof, netstat,  tcpdump etc to filter out incoming connections to 3306 port